# Why this regular expresion doesn't accept when I write the conditions in sequence?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression for a password with these conditions:

1- The password must contains 4 letters at least.

2- The password must contains 2 digits.

3- The password must contains 2 punctuation symbols.

4- The password must have a minimum length of 8 characters.

This is the regular expresion that I have: `"^((?=.*?\\p{L}.{4,})(?=.*?\\p{N}.{2,})(?=.*?\\p{P}.{2,})).{8,}$"`

And my problem is that yhis expresion doesn't accept this as password an I don't know why: "abcd12.-".

Can anyone help me with this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: You could use the quantifier for the groups instead `^(?=(?:.*\p{L}){4})(?=(?:.*\p{N}){2,})(?=(?:.*\p{P}){2,}).{8,}$` https://regex101.com/r/0MEJ74/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in the expressions `(?=.*?\\p{L}.{4,}` checks if there is a letter followed by 4 or more times any character.

You could update your expression to use non capturing groups `(?:` and repeat the groups n times matching a letter, a number or punctuation instead.

```
 ^(?=(?:.*\\p{L}){4})(?=(?:.*\\p{N}){2})(?=(?:.*\\p{P}){2}).{8,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ulJdbZ/1)

Note that using `.{8,}` matches at least 8 times any character except a newline, also matching spaces.